# What is the most efficient way to store many coordinates in a database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a grid on which I'd like to show some elements. These elements I plan to store in a database. But with a grid of 30 by 20 there's a total of 600 possible coordinates to store with a value. On top of that the grid will have 2 overlapping layers, that would mean each user could have possibly 1200 coordinates.

This seems like a lot to me since I'm planning to implement this for a project that will have a large number of users.

> What would be the most efficient way to store a large number of
>   coordinates in a database, and to access coordinates for a large number of users?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: If you're talking about 1200 entries in a single table, that shouldn't be a problem at all.

Comment: Why do you need to store every possible coordinate for every user in the database?

Comment: I need to store the positions of the elements in the database so the users can access their personal grid as it was before.

Comment: This is what I was thinking of but don't know what is more efficient

- 1 record in a table with 1200 collumns
- json string in 1 field in 1 record
- 1 record in 2 tables with 600 collumns

Can't really think of any other way. Would any of these options suffice, and which would be more efficient?

Comment: You've decided on a database and on a specific database engine? Why.

Answer (score 0):

Absent other information, the normal database structure would be as table with columns such as:

- CoordinateId
- UserId
- xCoordinate
- yCoordinate
- Value1
- Value2

Having a couple thousand rows per user would normally not be a problem, particularly if you index the table properly (such as having a `userId` index).

But . . . the real answer depends on how this will be used.  Will new values be added?  Can the coordinates change?  How strict are the performance requirements?

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff for some new insight. I think i'd have to test this kind of thing. Because the grid would be frequently accessed.

Is there a way to simulate multiple users using the site?, that would be fun to test these different approaches aswell as educational.